# Сервер с асинхронным вводом/выводом TCP

Tags: c, сокет, multiprocessing

Доброго времени суток. У меня проблема. Есть клиенты, которые подключаются к серверу, им приходит сразу же строка hello с просьбой указать команду, потом сервер должен принять команду от клиента и выполнить одно из условий (отравить эхо, время или файл), а также клиент может отправить файл на сервер. Проблема в том, что в секцию if ((remoteSockDescr != servSockDescr) && FD_ISSET(remoteSockDescr, &readset)) вообще не заходит...

```
    // Заполняем множество сокетов
    fd_set readset; //в множество readset записываются дескрипторы сокетов, 
    //из которых нам требуется читать данные (слушающие сокеты добавляются в это же множество)
    fd_set writeset; //в множество writeset записываются дескрипторы сокетов, 
    //в которые нам требуется писать данные (читающие сокеты добавляются в это же множество)
    fd_set addrset; //для новых подключений
    int nfds = getdtablesize(); //макс число дескрипторов
    FD_ZERO(&readset); //очищает множество readset
    FD_ZERO(&writeset);
    FD_ZERO(&addrset);
    FD_SET(servSockDescr, &addrset); //добавляет дескриптор servSockDescr в множество addrset;

    printf("Waiting for connects... PID = %d\n", getpid());

    while (1) {
        memcpy(&readset, &addrset, sizeof(readset));
        memcpy(&writeset, &addrset, sizeof(writeset));

        //select засыпает в ожидании нового клиента на соединение или информацию
        if (select(nfds, &readset, &writeset, NULL, NULL) < 0) { //select на чтение.
            perror("Error in select function ");
            closeSock(servSockDescr);
            return -1;
        }            
        //после чего просыпаемся и определяем тип события и выполняем действия
        //после выполнения select в readset останутся только те дескрипторы, которые сработали на чтение
        if (FD_ISSET(servSockDescr, &readset)) { //сработал ли select на главном сокете 
            //поступил запрос на соединение
            remoteSockDescr = accept(servSockDescr, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &len);

            if (remoteSockDescr == -1) {
                perror("Error to accept the client");
                return -1;
            } else {
                char addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(cliaddr.sin_addr), addr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
                //setSocketUnblock(remoteSockDescr);
                FD_SET(remoteSockDescr, &addrset); //помещаем новый дескриптор в addrset
                printf("\nConnected a client with IP address %s\n", addr);
            }
        }

        for (remoteSockDescr = 0; remoteSockDescr < nfds; ++remoteSockDescr) {                
            if ((remoteSockDescr != servSockDescr) && FD_ISSET(remoteSockDescr, &writeset)) { //сработал ли select на запись в сокет     

                if (!strcmp(command, echo)) {//если пришло ECHO
                    printf("writeset - 2\n");
                    sendDataFromBuf(remoteSockDescr, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1, prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0);
                } else if (!strcmp(command, time)) { //если пришло TIME
                    printf("writeset - 3\n");
                    char *curTime = getCurrentTime();
                    sendDataFromBuf(remoteSockDescr, curTime, strlen(curTime) + 1, prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0);
                } else if (!strcmp(command, toClose)) { //если пришло CLOSE
                } else if (!strcmp(command, download)) { //если пришло DOWNLOAD
                    //TODO: отправить файл клиенту
                    sendFileToSocket(remoteSockDescr, buffer, prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0);
                } else {
                    if (sendDataFromBuf(remoteSockDescr, hello, strlen(hello) + 1, prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0) <= 0) {
                        closeSock(remoteSockDescr);
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error to send the invitation\n");
                    }
                }
                closeSock(remoteSockDescr);
                FD_CLR(remoteSockDescr, &addrset);
            }

            if ((remoteSockDescr != servSockDescr) && FD_ISSET(remoteSockDescr, &readset)) { //сработал ли select на чтение из сокета
                if (!strcmp(command, upload)) { //если пришло UPLOAD
                    //TODO: загрузить файл на сервер
                    receiveFileFromSocket(remoteSockDescr, buffer, prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0);
                } else {
                    if (recieveDataToBuf(remoteSockDescr, buffer, sizeof(buffer), prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0) <= 0) {
                        closeSock(remoteSockDescr);
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error to get the command\n");
                    } else separString(buffer, command);
                }
                memset(buffer, 0, sizeof (buffer));
                memset(command, 0, sizeof (buffer));
                closeSock(remoteSockDescr);
                FD_CLR(remoteSockDescr, &addrset);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `memcpy(&readset, &addrset, sizeof(readset));` — так делать нельзя, надо отдельно добавлять в readset и writeset; `nfds` — должен быть реальный максимальный открытый дескриптор, а не максимальный доступный в системе. `command`, вероятно, должна быть отдельная для каждого клиента. Во `writeset` должны быть **только** дескрипторы клиентов отложенные для записи. Возможны и другие ошибки... ЗЫ: если не принципиально, то у `poll ()` ИМХО куда более разумный интерфейс.

Comment: И вы после accept не ставите на сокет O_NONBLOCK, что может заблокировать вас на первой же попытке чтения

Answer (score 0):

Я не понимаю логики данного кода. Смотрите, что у Вас написано:

```
FD_ZERO(&addrset);
. . .
memcpy(&readset, &addrset, sizeof(readset));
memcpy(&writeset, &addrset, sizeof(writeset));
```

Сейчас оба набора (readset и  writeset) - **пустые** !
После этого Вы выдаёте:

```
select(nfds, &readset, &writeset, NULL, NULL);
```

А чего ждёт этот *select* ?! Ведь у него все наборы файловых селекторов - пустые! Вот он и висит на бесконечном ожидании.

На практике, что бы реализовать на сервере обработку множества поступающих запросов на соединение, поступают следующим образом:

1. Создают начальный *слушающий* сокет
2. Заносят fd этого сокета в *readset*
3. Организуют бесконечный цикл, первым оператором которого является *select*
4. Когда *select* соскакивает с ожидания (появился запрос) выполняется вызов *accept*
5. **Новый** дескриптор сокета, который вернул *accept* передаётся функции, которая обрабатывает запрос
6. Основной цикл возвращается на *select*

Comment: попробую так сделать. новые дескрипторы занести в массив? и потом в цикле for() их проверять на наличие условие срабатывания?

Comment: Cовершенно верно.  Слушающий сокет добавляете в *readset*, а после соскока с *select* проверяете его с помощью  FD_ISSET.

Comment: Не забудьте только сделать *listen()* на слушающий сокет.

Comment: помогите еще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769002/Параллельный-сервер-tcp-с-помощью-мультиплексирования-select