# Параллельный сервер TCP с помощью мультиплексирования (select)

Tags: c, сокет, tcp

Доброго времени суток. У меня проблема. Есть клиенты, которые подключаются к серверу, сервер должен принять команду от клиента и выполнить одно из условий (отравить/принять файлы). Проблема в том, что если я ставлю слушающий сокет и дескрипторы клиентов в неблокирующий режим, то у меня пересылается только около 300 кб и дальше функции recv/send выдают -1, а в блокирующем режиме (как для слушающего так и для клиентов) клиенты становятся в очередь и ждут пока предыдущий отправит/загрузит файлы, т.е. нет никакой параллельности работы...

```
    //структура клиента
    struct fileInfo {
    int sock;
    FILE *file;
    };
    //....main() {
    ....
    // Заполняем множество сокетов
    fd_set rset;                        //множество readset 
    fd_set allset;                      //для новых подключений

    int i, nready;
    int maxfd = servSockDescr;           //инициальзация максимального дескриптора
    int maxi = -1;                      //макисмальный индекс в client[] 

    struct fileInfo client[FD_SETSIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++) {
        client[i].sock = -1;
        client[i].file = NULL;
    }

    FD_ZERO(&allset);
    FD_SET(servSockDescr, &allset);     //добавляет дескриптор servSockDescr в множество addrset;

    printf("Waiting for connects...\n");

    for (; ; ) {
        rset = allset;                  //назначение структуры rset

        if (nready = select(maxfd + 1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) { //select на чтение.
            continue;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(servSockDescr, &rset)) {           //новое подключение клиента

            remoteSockDescr = accept(servSockDescr, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &len);
            if (remoteSockDescr == -1) {
                perror("Error to accept the client");
                return -1;
            } else {
                //setSocketUnblock(remoteSockDescr);
                char addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(cliaddr.sin_addr), addr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
                printf("\nConnected a client with IP address %s port %d\n\n", addr, ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));
            }

            for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++) {
                if (client[i].sock < 0) {
                    client[i].sock = remoteSockDescr; //сохраняем дескриптор
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i == FD_SETSIZE)
                perror("too many clients");

            FD_SET(remoteSockDescr, &allset); //добавляем новый дескриптор в набор
            if (remoteSockDescr > maxfd)
                maxfd = remoteSockDescr;      //если дескриптор больше максимального
            if (i > maxi)
                maxi = i;                    // максимальный индекс в client[]

        }

        for (i = 0; i <= maxi; i++) {        //проверить всех клиентов на данные
            if (client[i].sock < 0)
                continue;
            if (FD_ISSET(client[i].sock, &rset)) { //если чтение из сокета

                if (recieveDataToBuf(client[i].sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0) <= 0) { //принять 
                    perror("Error to get the command");
                }
                else {
                    separString(buffer, command);                               //разбить на части
                    if (!strcmp(command, echo)) {                               //если пришло ECHO
                        sendDataFromBuf(client[i].sock, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1, prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0);
                    }
                    else if (!strcmp(command, time)) {                          //если пришло TIME
                        char *curTime = getCurrentTime();
                        sendDataFromBuf(client[i].sock, curTime, strlen(curTime) + 1, prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0);
                    }
                    else if (!strcmp(command, toClose)) {                       //если пришло CLOSE
                    }
                    else if (!strcmp(command, download)) {                      //если пришло DOWNLOAD
                        //TODO: отправить файл клиенту
                        client[i].file = fopen(buffer, "rb");

                        if (client[i].file == NULL) {
                            perror("Error to open the file");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }

                        sendFileToSocket(client[i], buffer, prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0);
                    }
                    else if (!strcmp(command, upload)) {                        //если пришло UPLOAD
                        //TODO: загрузить файл на сервер
                        receiveFileFromSocket(client[i], buffer, prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0);
                    }
                    else sendDataFromBuf(client[i].sock, error, strlen(error) + 1, prtcl.tcp, NULL, 0);
                }

                memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                memset(command, 0, sizeof(buffer));

                closeSock(client[i].sock);
                FD_CLR(client[i].sock, &allset);
                client[i].sock = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    void sendFileToSocket(fileInfo newClient, char *buffer, const char *protocol, sockaddr_in *remote, socklen_t rlen) {
    char fileSize[256] = { '\0' };
    sprintf(fileSize, "%ld", getFileSize(newClient.file));

    if (sendDataFromBuf(newClient.sock, fileSize, sizeof(fileSize), protocol, remote, rlen) <= 0) {
        printf("Error sending the file's size %s\n", fileSize);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    long totalBytesSent = 0;
    if ((totalBytesSent = sendDataFromFile(newClient.sock, newClient.file, getFileSize(newClient.file), protocol, remote, rlen)) <= 0) {
        printf("Error sending the file: %s\n", buffer);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    }

    int sendDataFromBuf(int descriptor, const char *buf, int len, const char *protocol, sockaddr_in *remote, socklen_t rlen) {
    int numberOfBytesSent;

    numberOfBytesSent = send(descriptor, buf, len, 0);

    if (numberOfBytesSent < 0) {
    perror("Error to send data from buffer");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return numberOfBytesSent;
    }

    long sendDataFromFile(int descriptor, FILE *file, long fileSize, const char *protocol, sockaddr_in *remote, socklen_t rlen) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    long totalBytesSent = 0;
    size_t bytesRead = 0;

    while (totalBytesSent < fileSize) {
        bytesRead = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), file);
        int sentBytes = send(descriptor, buf, bytesRead, 0);
        if (sentBytes < 0) {
            perror("Error to send data from the file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        totalBytesSent += sentBytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: recv/send выдают -1, а errno == EAGAIN? Если так, то все нормально, нужно ждать (для send запоминать, сколько байт уже нормально отправили), потом продолжать. У вас я совсем не вижу кода для такой обработки

Comment: @avp я уже 3 дня бьюсь и не знаю как это правильно реализовать

Comment: Асинхронно с неблокирующими сокетами?

Comment: @avp да! чтобы не было блокировки

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сразу сделать законченную отсылку/прием файла. Поэтому и не работает.  Прежде всего, вам надо использовать 3-й параметр select (`fd_set *writefds`). (или перейти с select на poll, мне кажется с ним удобней, но это не принципиально)  А принципиально то, что надо хранить контекст каждого соединения и обрабатывать изменения по мере их поступления. Для отсылки придется завести буфер, связанный с каждым соединением, и отправлять его части по мере того, как сокет становится writable и дочитывать в него из файла, когда там мало данных. Аналогичные проблемы могут быть и с чтением команд

Comment: @avp я решил проблему с errno == EAGAIN, но вот одновременное чтение из 2-х файлов в одном потоке так и не смог реализовать...

Comment: Смотрите. Вы в цикле после select идете по сокетам и видите, что сокет writable и еще не все данные файла отправлены. Если буфер на отправку пуст, то читаете очередной кусок файла (скажем 4 килобайт) и пытаетесь его отправить. Если отправилось 100 байт, то остаток будет у вас в буфере, связанном с этим сокетом. Если перед отправкой  в буфере осталось мало данных, то можно дочитать до 4К из файла, а потом отправлять.  Потом просто переходите к следующему сокету и отправляете кусочек его файла. И т.д. по кругу.

Comment: @avp некрасиво получится... придется выворачивать все функции и  городить все в main-е... завтра попробую и если что вам отпишусь. а есть для связи что-нибудь?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71495/discussion-between-avp-and-dzmitry).